# constraints on "anything but"

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, ambiguity

Are these examples are all acceptable and illustrative of the same use of **anything but**? What constraints, if any, are at work?

> 1. He looked **anything but** happy.
> 2. He did **anything but** watch TV. (= ? He did not watch TV.)
> 3. He did not do **anything but** watch TV.
> 4. He will do **anything but** watch TV. (= ? He will not watch TV.)
> 5. He will decide to do **anything but** watch TV.

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: Are you asking about these phrases as spoken or as written?

Comment: Maybe both. Have you noticed any difference when one mode rather than the other is used?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the difference between those sentences on the one hand (if they are natural) and "They called the house anything but the Pyramid" (which I asked about the other day).

Comment: What do you mean by "one mode"? Your other question was about "anything but" versus "anything else but". Otherwise, every sentence ***here*** is exactly like the "anything-but-the Pyramid" question. Why would they differ? And where, pray tell, is the mode?

Comment: @Lambie I'm referring to "mode" because Tᴚoɯɐuo refers to "spoken" and "written." He seems to assume there's a difference.

Comment: By constraints, do you mean what follows "anything but"? She was not doing **anything but answering** the questions....

Comment: Depending upon the meaning the speaker wishes to convey, a natural syntactic pause could occur before or after **anything**.   There can be ambiguity if that syntactic pause is not clearly represented in text with punctuation.  *He will agree  to do anything, but renege.*  Paraphrase: No matter what you ask of him, he will agree to do it, but he always reneges.  *He will do anything but renege*.  Paraphrase: I can assure you, he will not renege.  We need to know whether **anything but** is to be understood as a single constituent. The two words *can* occur in sequence but not belong together.

Comment: Are these examples of "anything but" of the same type as "anything but" as in "To have called the house anything but the Pyramid was a stupid mistake"?

Comment: The difference between your pyramid example and the examples you give in this question is that the pyramid is a noun-phrase and here you're using a combination of adjectives and infinitive clauses.

Comment: Some people say "anything but" in #4 is not an idiom by a sequence of two words. I'm wondering whether that's also the case in the Pyramid example.

Comment: And #2 is said to be unnatural.

Comment: #2 is grammatical but the simple past **did** can appear odd and not idiomatic. I understand the sentence to be a statement by someone who had observed "his" behavior over a period of time and is now reporting that "he" did a very wide variety of things but at no time did he watch TV; he downright avoided TV.   **did anything but** is an unidiomatic way to report that ongoing behavior.  **would do anything but** or **was doing anything but** would be idiomatic.

Comment: Having first established the ongoing nature of the reported action using **would do** or **was doing**, you could then go on to say *He did anything but watch TV.*  That we have to conjure up that context is what makes it seem unnatural "on its face".

Comment: In general you provide very little context in the example statements given in your questions, and it is often context which determines whether an utterance is natural or unnatural.

Comment: If you want to tell a third party that Joe eats most things but has an aversion to bananas and so the third party should not *expect* him to eat bananas:  *He **will** eat anything but bananas* would be OK.  The simple fact without the nuance of expectation could be expressed with the simple present: *He eats anything but bananas.*

Comment: ***He'll* eat anything but bananas** can mean "Don't serve him bananas." "Don't expect him to eat bananas." "I've come to know that he will refuse a banana offered to him".  **He eats anything but bananas** is a more neutral, unnuanced statement of the fact.  The future tense has some implication.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is fine.

As for #2 and #4, talking about the person who avoids TV, you can either speak as though the situation is ongoing (if the person still doesn't watch TV), or speak of it as something that was true at some time in the past (such as when the person is deceased, or if the person formally avoided television but now watches regularly). These seem like natural ways to say these:

- He will do anything but watch TV. (ongoing)
- He would do anything but watch TV. (no longer true)

As for your #3 option:

> He did not do anything but watch TV.

that means he watched television **all the time**, at the exclusion of all other activities. To emphasize that's true in the present, you would say:

> He doesn't do anything but watch TV.